# Generating POST messages using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, curl, afnetworking

So, I get JSON to return from my web service using a command like this in terminal:

```
curl --data 'method=my-service.search&document_type=x&keywords=y' http://mywebsite.com/services/json/my-service.search
```

And I've been trying to get this data through AFNetworking for parsing and use in an app. So far, this is what I have tried:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"document_type", @"keywords", nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
```

I set the URL string to http://mywebsite.com/services/json/my-service.search and the dictionary is supposed to contain the parameters for searching.

But I get an error saying that the request failed due to "unacceptable content-type: text/html" (obviously, it wants JSON).

So my question is as follows: How do you perform a cURL data request through AFNetworking?

I have a bonus question as well: how do you interact with the parameters in the dictionary (say, set the keyword field to "Stack Overflow" or something like that)?

Thanks for the help! I'm just starting out, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify content-type with this:

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

But first of all make sure you set propert request serializer:

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

It should set content type automatically

Also use POST: instead of GET:

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get the same error even with your changes, which leads me to believe that I'm not making the cURL request properly. Any experience with converting a command line POST generation request to an AFNetworking request?

Comment: You are making GET instead of POST. Use POST: method from manager... There is no way to use command line POST and AFNetworking.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I've given that a try, but received the same error. I think that I am formatting the parameters incorrectly.